# Apex UPDATE result is not visible by SELECT happening afterwards

Tags: apex, soql, pdf, update

A question to those who may have some background over Salesforce stack. I would like to confirm if my suspicions may be right.

In APEX controller I'm doing following set of operations: setting attribute of object, updating it in the database and calling a method `generatePDF()`.

```
invoice.Status__c = 'Issued';
update invoice;
generatePDF(invoice);
```

`generatePDF()` in my logic is calling standardized method reused for various objects. Therefore it queries again `invoice` object almost immediately after `UPDATE` to retrieve all the details of the object again. I would expect the result of `SELECT` to contain updated status, however it doesn't happen.

Quick look at the logs with timestamps (first line is result of `UPDATE`, second - result of `SELECT`):

```
15:35:48:275 USER_DEBUG [286]|DEBUG|Invoice__c:{... Status__c=Issued}  
15:35:49:173 USER_DEBUG [154]|DEBUG|Invoice__c:{... Status__c=Planned}
```

So `SELECT` that is happening after `UPDATE` doesn't see that update happened. If I delay `SELECT` by a second - everything works as expected - both have correct status.

The only thing that I can imagine is that this is happening because of multitenancy - the code is executed by different threads that are accessing different memory pools / different databases and don't get in sync... (btw. what is this [286] next to USER_DEBUG in logs?).

Anybody can explain that strange behaviour?

If not - is there any way to wait for a callback from DML operation in APEX? Something like:

```
update( invoice, onSuccess() {
    generatePDF();
}, onError() {
    'rollback';
});
```

Thanks for help,
Maciek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that the PDF generation (e.g. via [PageReference.getContentAsPdf](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm)) operates in a separate transaction and the controller has not committed its changes when you are generating the PDF. As there is no explicit commit available in Apex, there is no way to get the PDF generation done synchronously within the one controller because of this.

One work around is to do the PDF generation asynchronously using e.g. an @future method that the controller calls. This is guaranteed to be after the controller has committed its changes as recording that the @future needs to run is in itself a database operation. But this can be confusing to users where the PDF sometimes may appear immediately (e.g. if it is added as an Attachment) but other times take many seconds to appear.

Another work-around (if the PDF generation is at the end of the controller) is for the final controller method to return the PDF generation URL and for that controller to create the PDF and then return the final destination URL.